# ValueError : Linkname is too long

Tags: android, python, ubuntu-14.04, kivy

While building apk using python for android using command `./build.py --dir /home/sahil/Desktop/kivy --package org.demo.kivy --name Kivy --version 1.0 debug` I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./build.py", line 508, in <module>
make_package(args)
File "./build.py", line 332, in make_package
make_tar('assets/public.mp3', [args.dir], args.ignore_path)
File "./build.py", line 203, in make_tar
tf.add(fn, afn)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2005, in add
self.addfile(tarinfo)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 2018, in addfile
buf = tarinfo.tobuf(self.format, self.encoding, self.errors)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 993, in tobuf
return self.create_ustar_header(info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tarfile.py", line 1007, in create_ustar_header
raise ValueError("linkname is too long")
 ValueError: linkname is too long
```

I looked on internet and also in documentation but didn't find anything.
HELP!

Comment: What is `fn` and `afn`?

Comment: Its in the build.py file, it's auto genetated after `./distribute.sh` command is used in process to make .apk in python-for-android.

Comment: In my case the "link" being rejected is '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/__future__.py', which is 102 bytes. The `python3.5/tarfile.py` which is complaining will reject anything beyong 100 bytes, according to `LENGTH_LINK = 100 # maximum length of a linkname`; I'm feeling reluctant to move the python installation. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the path leading to where you are trying to build is especially long? it seems this error can happen when a filename is too long for tar to handle, if you could add a `print(fn, afn)` before line 203 of build.py, to check what's the filename that is tried. Or maybe move the whole project to /tmp to build and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check to see if your python-for-android folder is inside your project directory (/home/sahil/Desktop/kivy)?

I was getting this error too until I moved the python-for-android folder outside the directory with my kivy code and whatnot. Then I was able to build the apk successfully.